# Error in execSQL in running app on phone

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

I've created an app that will set an alarm for a specified date and store some data for this alarm in a database. The app works fine in my emulator but when I try to run it on my phone it crashes. I managed to trace the source of the crash to this line of code:

```
String newTableQueryString = "create table" + TABLE_NAME + " (" + TABLE_ROW_ID + 
"integer primary key autoincrement not null," + TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text" +");";
// execute the query string to the database. This is what's causing the crash
db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Try uninstalling the application from the device and then install again

Comment: log your full sql query and write it here down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're lacking spaces in some places, so final SQL string migth be incorrect. For instance add space after `create table` string, like here

```
String newTableQueryString = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + ...
```